# Why jsessionid not work while redirecting from maindomain to subdomain?

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, jsessionid

There are no of `portal url (subdomain)` exist with ``organization url (main domain)` in web application.

Example:

**Organization url (main domain):**

```
etender.in
```

**Portal url (sub domain):**

```
health.etender.in 
pnb.etender.in
```

There is one button on dashboard from where user can redirect either organization or portal url after login, but It should not ask login details once he entered and logged in with app until he logged out.

*Case 1: (This is working)*

From organization url, user want to redirect to portal urt, it will load dashboard (a screen after loging in application) and don't ask login info again.

*Case 2: (This is not working)*

From portal url, user wants to redirect on organization url, it will ask login validation and not load dashboard.

I thought that it may be different domain name.

When I debug through firebug, **jsessionid** was different in second case but it was same in first case.

I don't understand, why was it same in first redirect and not in second redirect? is there any approach to work in both case?